# How to use regular expressions inside C# MongoDB Driver aggregate pipeline

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb, aggregate, pipeline

I would like to make a query in C# in MongoDB and show the result in a datagrid.
In my query method's pipeline I first want to filter year. 
However, in my MongoDB database there is no value with the year only. I only got date values.
So my idea was to use a regular expression to filter the year out of the date value. The key for that date value is `Bestelldatum`.

I tried the following regular expression which I found in the MongoDB documentation but it is not working. It gives me an error (`$regexMatch not recognized`):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/#exp._S_regexMatch

```
public List<T> MeistenHv<T>(string coll, string year)
    {
        /* Pipeline anlegen */
        //Alle Dokumente mit dem angegebenen Jahr
        var regex = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$addFields", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "results", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"$regexMatch", new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "input", "$Bestelldatum" },
                                    { "regex", year}
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        //Gruppiert nach Hv, bei jedem Treffer um 1 inkrementieren
        var group = new BsonDocument
        {
                { "$group", new BsonDocument
                           {
                                {"_id", new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            {"Hv", "$Hv"}
                                        }
                                },
                                {"uniqueIds", new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            {"$addToSet", "$_id"}
                                        }
                                },
                                {"count", new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            {"$sum", 1 }
                                        }
                                }
                           }
                }
        };

        //Absteigend sortiert nach der Häufigkeit der Hv
        var sort = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$sort", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"count", -1 }
                }                    
            }
        };

        var pipeline = new[] { regex, group, sort };

        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(coll);           
        var data = collection.Aggregate<T>(pipeline).ToList();

        return data;
    }
```

I also tried this with the same error:

```
 var regex = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
               "$regex", new BsonDocument
               {
                   { "Bestelldatum", year}
               }
            }
        };
```

[image]

**EDIT:** (included sampledoc json)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e31bb10c1b1e773e46be7f8"),
"LsNr" : "L1016",
"Bv" : "Blahblah",
"Hv" : "27292",
"Bauleiter" : "Jonathan Fakename",
"Projektleiter" : "Patrick NotMyRealName",
"Besteller" : "zuwenig auf Baustelle",
"Abholer" : "Herr Brown",
"Lagerort" : "Lager",
"Bemerkung" : null,
"Status" : "gebucht",
"Sachbearbeiter" : "",
"Abholdatum" : null,
"Beleg" : "L1016",
"Umsatz" : "39.39",
"Gegenkonto" : "5999",
"Buchungsdatum" : "22.08.2018",
"Konto" : "5150",
"Kost1" : null,
"Kost2" : "27292",
"Text" : "Blahblah",
"Bestelldatum" : "22.08.2018",
"Heute" : "29.01.2020",
"artikelliste" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e31bb10c1b1e773e46be7f4"),
        "Menge" : "1",
        "Bezeichnung" : "My great article",
        "Einheit" : "Eimer",
        "Anforderungsgrund" : null,
        "Einzelpreis" : "2.91",
        "Gesamtpreis" : "29.1",
        "Mgkzswert" : "31.43",
        "Mgkzssatz" : "8",
        "LetztesUpdate" : "29.01.2020 18:04:16",
        "PersonUpdate" : "username",
        "Kommentar" : null
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e31bb10c1b1e773e46be7f5"),
        "Menge" : "1",
        "Bezeichnung" : "What an awesome article",
        "Einheit" : "Stück",
        "Anforderungsgrund" : null,
        "Einzelpreis" : "3.98",
        "Gesamtpreis" : "3.98",
        "Mgkzswert" : "4.3",
        "Mgkzssatz" : "8",
        "LetztesUpdate" : "29.01.2020 18:04:16",
        "PersonUpdate" : "username",
        "Kommentar" : null
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e31bb10c1b1e773e46be7f6"),
        "Menge" : "1",
        "Bezeichnung" : "Great articles you have here man",
        "Einheit" : "Stück",
        "Anforderungsgrund" : null,
        "Einzelpreis" : "1.69",
        "Gesamtpreis" : "1.69",
        "Mgkzswert" : "1.83",
        "Mgkzssatz" : "8",
        "LetztesUpdate" : "29.01.2020 18:04:16",
        "PersonUpdate" : "username",
        "Kommentar" : null
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e31bb10c1b1e773e46be7f7"),
        "Menge" : "1",
        "Bezeichnung" : "Is it available in huge, too?",
        "Einheit" : "Stück",
        "Anforderungsgrund" : null,
        "Einzelpreis" : "1.69",
        "Gesamtpreis" : "1.69",
        "Mgkzswert" : "1.83",
        "Mgkzssatz" : "8",
        "LetztesUpdate" : "29.01.2020 18:04:16",
        "PersonUpdate" : "username",
        "Kommentar" : null
    }
]
```

}

Here is my mapped model class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
    using MongoDB.Bson;

    namespace Lieferscheine.Models
    {
        public class 

LieferscheinModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //ATTRIBUTE      
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id;
        public string Bauleiter { get; set; }
        public string Projektleiter { get; set; }
        public string Besteller { get; set; }
        public string Abholer { get; set; }
        public string Lagerort { get; set; }
        public string Bemerkung { get; set; }
        //rechts   
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Sachbearbeiter { get; set; }
        public string Abholdatum { get; set; }
        public string Buchungsdatum { get; set; }
        public string Konto { get; set; }
        public string Kost1 { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel> _artikel = new ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel>();
        private string _heute = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        private string _bestelldatum;

        //************************************************************************************
        //PROPERTIES
        private string _lsNr;
        public string LsNr
        {
            get
            {
                return _lsNr;
            }
            set
            {
                _lsNr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LsNr");
                Beleg = _lsNr;
            }
        }
        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        private string _hv;
        public string Hv
        {
            get { return _hv; }
            set
            {
                _hv = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Hv");
                Kost2 = _hv;
            }
        }

        private string _bv;
        public string Bv
        {
            get { return _bv; }
            set
            {
                _bv = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Bv");
                Text = _bv;
            }
        }

        private string _beleg;
        public string Beleg
        {
            get { return _beleg; }
            set
            {
                _beleg = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Beleg");
            }
        }

        private string _gegenkonto = "5999";
        public string Gegenkonto
        {
            get { return _gegenkonto; }
            set
            {
                _gegenkonto = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Gegenkonto");
            }
        }


        private decimal _umsatz = 0;

        public decimal Umsatz
        {
            get { return _umsatz; }
            set
            {
                _umsatz = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Umsatz");
            }
        }

        private string _kost2;

        public string Kost2
        {
            get { return _kost2; }
            set
            {
                _kost2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Kost2");
            }
        }


        public string Bestelldatum
        {
            get { return _bestelldatum; }
            set
            {
                _bestelldatum = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Bestelldatum");
            }
        }
        public string Heute
        {
            get { return _heute; }
            set { _heute = value; } //private hinzufügen!
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel> artikelliste
        {
            get { return _artikel; }
            set
            {
                _artikel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("artikelliste");
            }
        }

        // *******************************************************************************


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public LieferscheinModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need regex to match the year. build your pipeline like this:

```cs
var collection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
                    .GetDatabase("test")
                    .GetCollection<BsonDocument>("LieferscheinModel");

var year = "2018";

PipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> matchStage = $@"
{{
  $match: {{
    $expr: {{
      $eq: [
        {{
          $year: {{
            $toDate: ""$Bestelldatum""
          }}
        }},
        {year}
      ]
    }}
  }}
}}";

PipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> groupStage = @"
{
  $group: {
    _id: ""$Hv"",
    uniqueIds: {
      $addToSet: ""$_id""
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}";

PipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> sortStage = @"
{
  $sort: {
    count: -1
  }
}";

var pipeline = new[] { matchStage, groupStage, sortStage };

var result = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
```

Comment: Sadly my dates are not of type ISO but strings. Hence I get the following error when trying your solution:`Command aggregate failed: can't convert from BSON type string to Date`. Any workaround?

Comment: This seems to work now but I get another error which has probably something to do with the other candidates in my pipeline:`An error occurred while deserializing the _id field of class Lieferscheine.Models.LieferscheinModel: Cannot deserialize a 'String' form BsonType 'Document'`. I suppose the error occurs because of this?: namespace Lieferscheine.Models
{
    public class LieferscheinModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //ATTRIBUTE      
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id;

Comment: Could you help me solve the rest of it in chat, please? I feel pretty burnt out right now.

Comment: @timunix I'm away from a computer right now. I'll have a look at it as soon as I can. is Hv a property on your class? what is it's type? string? if you add a sample json doc from the DB would help.

Comment: I edited my question, adding a json doc from the db to it. Yes, Hv is a string property on my class. I'll add the Model class in a minute.

Comment: @timunix updated the answer. i think the problem was with your group key.

Comment: I will mark this answer as solved because the method is working now. The problem I have is that the return type is not the one I expected. Instead of returning List<LieferscheinModel> I have List<BsonDocument>. The returned List is supposed to show the values 2 datagrids (1 main datagrid --> click row --> subdatagrid shows array values of main datagrid). This is not working now because main datagrid expects List<LieferscheinModel> and subdatagrid List<ArtikelModel>. I am going to open another question for that.